# iphone SDK 4.0 NSURL and assets-library://

Tags: ios4

Is it not possible to access the Assets library in the background even with UIBackgroundTask? Do the enumerators work only when the application is in active state?

Also, can one use the "assets-library://" url with NSURL or other API apart from the Assets-Library framework?

Thanks!